# Custom field in backend with new extensions

Tags: typo3

When I build a new extension with Quickstarter, I customize how the backend with the file ext_tables.php, using this line:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['types'][$_EXTKEY . '_pi1']['showitem'] = 'CType, header,media;Images';
```

Where I can add new fields and even rename them. But sometimes I find weird sufixes to each field like, for example, "media;;;;1-1-1" which control other stuff that appear around the controls in the backend.

How can I know what these codes mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [TCA Documentation](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.6.0/view/1/3/#id2628695) there is a description of the types-section ($TCA['tt_content']['types']). In there is a table, where ['showitem'] is explained.

```
Part 1: Field name reference (Required!)

Part 2: Alternative field label (string or LLL reference)

Part 3: Palette number (referring to an entry in the "palettes" section).

Part 4: Special configuration (split by colon ( : )), e.g. 'nowrap' and 'richtext[(list of keys or *)]' (see “Additional $TCA features”)

Part 5: Form style codes (see “Visual style of TCEforms”)
```

Comment: wow, that seems really complicated... is there an easier way to configure them? :S

Comment: you can just ignore it. Instead "image;;;;1-1-1" use "image".